# Four-Colour Theorem Inquiry with handmade graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I recently came across the 4-color theorem and tried to see if it worked with all maps just for fun, although I know it has been proved by mathematician much smarter than me.

I opened up Microsoft paint and started just doodling graphs until I drew one where I couldn't find just 4 colors to fill it in.  It's attached below.  Would anyone know how to solve it?  Or am I missing a condition of the theorem?

[image]

Comment: The nose and hair don't touch, so they can use the same color.

Answer (score 2):

We can color it like this.[image]

If you want to color a planar graph, it is best to start with the vertex with highest degree. So you will eliminate available colors faster.

Comment: You're a genius, I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thanks.